# Using Jsoup how do I got through multiple URLS

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm creating a web **scraper** where it goes through multiple URLS from the same domain. I have a text file with a list of URLS. I used the readAllBytes method so I can read the text file and stored it in a String.
This is the error I'm getting when I run the program. I'm not sure what it causing the Illegal character in the URL.

```
Illegal character in URL
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.checkURL(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.<init>(HttpURLConnection.java:857)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:979)
at com.web.DogsDataExtractorV.GetAllDogsData(DogsDataExtractorV.java:74)
at com.web.DogsDataExtractorV.main(DogsDataExtractorV.java:115)
```

This is the part of my code where I store the text file in a string and also where I specify the string for the urls,

```
try {
            Path file_Path = Paths.get("/home/c/cerda/DogsData/upload", "dog-links.txt");
            byte[] link_list = Files.readAllBytes(file_Path);
            String Link_String = new String(link_list);
            System.out.println(Link_String);
            GetAllDogsData(Link_String);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
```

and this is the part of the code where I set up where to look the information and save the data to.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, null);
        Elements resulCharact = doc.select(("span[class=characteristic item-trigger-title]"));
        for (Element link : resulCharact ) {
            writeToFile("../upload/characteristic.txt", link.text()+ "\n");
      }
        Elements resulRating = doc.select(("span[class=star-block stars-column]"));
        for (Element ratings : resulRating) {
            writeToFile("../upload/ratings.txt", ratings.text()+ "\n");

        }
```

text file sample

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/boerboel

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/bolognese

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/border-collie

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/border-terrier

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/borzoi

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/boston-terrier

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/bouvier-des-flandres

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/boxer

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/boykin-spaniel

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/bracco-italiano

http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/briard

The code works with one url. If anyone can help thank you.

Comment: It says: "Illegal character in URL" What is the URL you are trying to connect to when it complains?

Comment: Can you update the question to show a sample of the text file?

Comment: @Justin I updated my question with the sample of the text file and others things I changed. I'm still having the same issue with the Illegal character in URL.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception you're getting clearly states the problem - `Illegal character in URL`. That means that you're passing something that isn't a URL into `URL.openConnection`. I suspect that it's because of the way in which you are reading the file - why are you passing `\\A` as the delimiter? If there are mutliple URLs in there, that will cause the `Scanner` to return all of them at once. That's why it's working when there's only one URL in the file.

Use the actual character(s) that delimit the URLs in the file, and read them out one by one.

Comment: now I get this `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's not because of the different delimiter. This error means that your program can't find the file at the specified location.

Comment: is only reading the first URL. Is there a better way to store a text file and make it to read it line by line ?

Comment: Keep calling Scanner's `next()`.

Comment: I updated my code a bit and made some changes, but still, I have not solved the illegal character problem I have.